# In the HTML Import polyfill, how do you get the imported content?

Tags: polymer

Under native HTML Imports, a `<link rel="import" href="...">` will, once loaded, have an `.import` property pointing to the imported document. Under the polyfill, this property does not seem to be available. (See http://jsbin.com/sifem/4/edit, which displays "Got content" in the console under native HTML Imports in Canary, and "No content" under the polyfill.)

How then can one reliably access imported content in code?

Comment: Seems like a bug/missing feature of the polyfill...but there might be good reason for it. Filed https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrote `onload="loaded(this)"` you bypassed the ShadowDOMPolyfill, so the reference received in `loaded` is unwrapped and unsuitable for use.

`addEventListener` doesn't have this problem:

http://jsbin.com/xokar/1/edit

You could also use `wrap`, like `onload = "loaded(wrap(this))"`, but it's best to avoid referring to `wrap|unwrap` if you can.

Comment: Thanks. I spend so much time in Canary these days, I keep forgetting about the need to wrap() in the polyfill!